# Regex match only if string is found once on multiple lines

Tags: regex

Similar questions have been asked before but i cant find anything that covers my scenario. I need a regex that only matches, if a certain string has been found only once on multiple lines. Given following lines:

```
  20    7c2f.80e9.0b33    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/27
  20    7c2f.80ee.c28c    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/47
  20    7c2f.80ee.c2af    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/47
  20    7c2f.80ee.c2fb    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/47
  20    7c2f.80f3.6daa    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/32
  20    7c2f.80f3.6df9    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/47
  20    7c2f.80f6.f3c8    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/30
  20    7c2f.80f6.f3fd    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/29
```

I need a regex that matches only if the interface has been found once in the string. What i have so far, but it does not work:

```
(Gi1\/0\/47)[\S\s]*(?!Gi1\/0\/47)
```

Test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/39yJWm/1

So for example, if I check with **Gi1/0/27** it should get a match because it occurs only once. If I check with **Gi1/0/47** it shouldn't give a match, cause it occurs 4 times. You only need to consider one interface checking in the regex, as i will loop thru the results with a different interface each time.

Comment: Why would you do this with a regex?

Comment: I am using Cisco Prime Infrastructure to do some compliance audit checks. It uses the Java base regex engine. I have to use regex for this as i do not have access to java functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not twice in the string: `(?s)^(?!.*Gi1/0/27.*Gi1/0/27).*Gi1/0/27`

```
 (?s)                              # Dot-all modifier
 ^                                 # BOS
 (?! .* Gi1/0/27 .* Gi1/0/27 )     # Not twice in string
 .* 
 Gi1/0/27                          # Must exist
```

Comment: I tested your string, but it still matches the Gi1/0/47 example: https://regex101.com/r/rBofdD/1

Comment: @sln: that regex works like a charm, thank you very much! Please write as solution, so i can accept it.

Comment: @sln: I get the negative lookahead but whats with the (?s-m), can you explain what it does?

Comment: @MarioJost - The inline modifier overrides the global defaults. Hey, just incase some online regex tester decides to flub your regex with some unwanted modifiers. `(?s-m)` says _Dot-All_ and not(-) _Multi-line_ mode. And, its already posted in my answer, along with the 3 down votes.. LOL

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I accepted your answer as resolution. on the regex tester and on the prime infrastructure it only work if I put the `(?s-m)` in front. the `(?s)` is not enough. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer helped me a lot! By the way just to make things more clear, you wrote that the pattern is not repeated two times, actually instead it checks that is not repeated more than once and not just twice. This is perfect this way for me because I didn't want to repeat more than once, but what you wrote could be a little misleading

Comment: @91DarioDev - It only checks if the pattern is repeated twice, not more than once. It is commented exactly what it does, not what it implies. `1 > 2 > 1e99` because there is no regex concept/construct that defines the notion of _`greater than`_. In regex it is better to comment as you think relative to what regex can do as opposed to an abstract idea (which can be put in parenthesis, as a footnote, if needed).

Answer (score 0):

That was tricky. Assuming that the data are in a file named `data` and you have GNU Sed, here you go:

```
PAT='Gi1/0/27' && sed -rne '\%'"${PAT}"'$%!d;${p;q0};h;:a;n;\%'"${PAT}"'$%q0;${g;p;q0};ba' data
```

(If using a tool like Sed is not an option, then, well, I think that you will probably want some kind of tool. This one is hard to do with a regex alone.)

Comment: Sadly, i cant use any tool and have to stick to plain regex within prime infrastructure.

Comment: I see. Interesting. In that case, it might depend on which regex engine Cisco Prime uses—whether it supports sufficiently advanced Perl-style features and so on. I am not familiar with that aspect. When you solve this, let us know how you did it.